Difference between running Gradle wrapper test task with "test" task name specified and without it
I am running Gradle test task on specified list of modules two ways:

running ./gradlew test :module1:test :module2:test :module3:test etc.
running ./gradlew :module1:test :module2:test :module3:test etc.

In first case execution takes about 3 minutes, but in second case about 20 seconds.
What is the key difference between these commands? Why the second one is much faster?
Tried to clean and invalidate project, the result is pretty same. Nothing special found in google or official doc.
